# Which dependency require a certain jar

Tags: spring, maven, jar, dependencies

While building my project using maven I am getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project initial: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project yummyNoddles.com:initial:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find org.springframe
>   work.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.7.0.M1 in
>   http://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update int erval of
>   spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

How can I find which jar in my pom.xml has a dependency to this jar?

thanks

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can open pom.xml with pom editor. Also netbeans should provide a dependency graph in its pom editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try with dependency plugin:  `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

Having maven installed in the command line, go to the folder where the pom is and type:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true
```

This will give you all the jars that depend on the one missing.

Do force a network update, do a

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: Was this what you where looking for, or some other thing?